# Got a bumblebee error: HP-Notebook bumblebeed[3064]: [XORG] (EE) Invalid isolated device specification

Tags: nvidia, hp, intel, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a HP Pavilion 15-n061sr (ENERGY STAR) laptop with 2 videocards: Nvidia Geforce 740M and Intel 4000 HD. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64 and Bumblebee by following these instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

Also installed nvidia-319-updates, nvidia-settings-319.

When I try: `optirun firefox`, I got error:

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE)

[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

In `/var/log/syslog` I got following error:

```
HP-Notebook bumblebeed[3064]: [XORG] (EE)  HP-Notebook

bumblebeed[3064]: [XORG] (EE) **Invalid isolated device specification**

HP-Notebook bumblebeed[3064]: [XORG] (EE)
```

I tried nvidia-331, nvidia-331-settings, but with this packages I got same error.
In google I found no mention of this error.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this a little bit late but I have fallen into the same issue.
If your nvidia card has an hexadecimal PCI-Bus number (maybe 0a:00:0) here might be solution (at least for me).

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/573

Find out where your bumblebeed binary is and then:

`sudo cp /usr/sbin/bumblebeed{,.orig}
sudo sed -i 's/PCI:%02x:%02x:%o/PCI:%02d:%02d:%d/' /usr/sbin/bumblebeed`